# How to add input[type="file"] to a Dawn contact form?

Tags: shopify, liquid

I'm creating a block with a custom contact form. I'm using a basic form template from the Dawn theme. I need to add an input to it for adding a file so that the user can attach one file or picture. How can I add this field? Can this be done without plugins? Will the file be sent when I send?

```js
{%- form 'contact', id: 'ContactForm', class: contact_form_class -%}
          <div class="contact__fields">
            <div class="field">
              <input
                class="field__input"
                autocomplete="name"
                type="text"
                id="ContactForm-name"
                name="contact[{{ 'templates.contact.form.name' | t }}]"
                value="{% if form.name %}{{ form.name }}{% elsif customer %}{{ customer.name }}{% endif %}"
                placeholder="{{ 'templates.contact.form.name' | t }}"
              >
              <label class="field__label" for="ContactForm-name">{{ 'templates.contact.form.name' | t }}</label>
            </div>
            <div class="field field--with-error">
              <input
                autocomplete="email"
                type="email"
                id="ContactForm-email"
                class="field__input"
                name="contact[email]"
                spellcheck="false"
                autocapitalize="off"
                value="{% if form.email %}{{ form.email }}{% elsif customer %}{{ customer.email }}{% endif %}"
                aria-required="true"
                {% if form.errors contains 'email' %}
                  aria-invalid="true"
                  aria-describedby="ContactForm-email-error"
                {% endif %}
                placeholder="{{ 'templates.contact.form.email' | t }}"
              >
              <label class="field__label" for="ContactForm-email">
                {{- 'templates.contact.form.email' | t }}
                <span aria-hidden="true">*</span></label
              >
              {%- if form.errors contains 'email' -%}
                <small class="contact__field-error" id="ContactForm-email-error">
                  <span class="visually-hidden">{{ 'accessibility.error' | t }}</span>
                  <span class="form__message">
                    {%- render 'icon-error' -%}
                    {{- form.errors.translated_fields.email | capitalize }}
                    {{ form.errors.messages.email -}}
                  </span>
                </small>
              {%- endif -%}
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="field">
            <textarea
              rows="10"
              id="ContactForm-body"
              class="text-area field__input"
              name="contact[{{ 'templates.contact.form.comment' | t }}]"
              placeholder="{{ 'templates.contact.form.comment' | t }}"
            >
                {{- form.body -}}
              </textarea>
            <label class="form__label field__label" for="ContactForm-body">
              {{- 'templates.contact.form.comment' | t -}}
            </label>
          </div>
          <div class="contact__button">
            <button type="submit" class="button">
              {{ 'templates.contact.form.send' | t }}
            </button>
          </div>
        {%- endform -%}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to add such kind of input in a `contact form`.

[Here](https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/customer-engagement/add-contact-form#optional-inputs) you can find the official Shopify documentation regarding `contact forms`, refer to it to have more details about the optional inputs that can be added to such a form.

Hope that helped!